# Adding extra column to table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I need your help because I have no idea how can I do this:

I have three MySQL tables:

**pcs_clubs**
id, shortname

**pcs_candidates**
id, id_compet, id_club, id_season

**pcs_matchs**
id, id_candidate_dom, id_candidate_ext, id_day, date_day, buts_dom, buts_ext, id_season, id_compet, validation

Sample data:

**pcs_clubs**

```
id   shortname
1    Barcelona
2    Real Madrid
3    Sevilla
4    Deportivo
5    Espanyol
6    Real Zaragoza
```

**pcs_candidates**

```
id   id_compet   id_club  id_season
1     1            1            1
2     1            2            1
3     1            3            1
4     1            4            1
5     1            5            1
6     1            6            1
```

**pcs_matchs**

```
+----+------------------+------------------+--------+------------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+------------+
| id | id_candidate_dom | id_candidate_ext | id_day | date_match | buts_dom | buts_ext | id_season | id_compet | validation |
+----+------------------+------------------+--------+------------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+------------+
| 1  | 1                | 6                | 1      | 2015-11-12 | 0        | 3        | 1         | 1         | 1          |
+----+------------------+------------------+--------+------------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+------------+
| 2  | 2                | 5                | 1      | 2015-11-12 | 2        | 2        | 1         | 1         | 1          |
+----+------------------+------------------+--------+------------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+------------+
| 3  | 3                | 4                | 1      | 2015-11-12 | 2        | 1        | 1         | 1         | 1          |
+----+------------------+------------------+--------+------------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+------------+
| 4  | 6                | 2                | 2      | 2015-11-17 | 3        | 1        | 1         | 1         | 1          |
+----+------------------+------------------+--------+------------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+------------+
| 5  | 4                | 1                | 2      | 2015-11-17 | 1        | 1        | 1         | 1         | 1          |
+----+------------------+------------------+--------+------------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+------------+
| 6  | 5                | 3                | 2      | 2015-11-17 | 1        | 2        | 1         | 1         | 1          |
+----+------------------+------------------+--------+------------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+------------+
| 7  | 3                | 6                | 3      | 2015-11-24 | 2        | 0        | 1         | 1         | 1          |
+----+------------------+------------------+--------+------------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+------------+
| 8  | 2                | 4                | 3      | 2015-11-24 | 3        | 1        | 1         | 1         | 1          |
+----+------------------+------------------+--------+------------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+------------+
| 9  | 1                | 5                | 3      | 2015-11-24 | 4        | 1        | 1         | 1         | 1          |
+----+------------------+------------------+--------+------------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+------------+
```

The next MySQL query successful generating league table of the desired competition and season:

```
SELECT
  shortname AS Team, Sum(P) AS P,Sum(W) AS W,Sum(D) AS D,Sum(L) AS L,
  SUM(F) as F,SUM(A) AS A,SUM(GD) AS GD,SUM(Pts) AS Pts
FROM(
  SELECT
    id_candidate_dom Team,
    1 P,
    IF(buts_dom > buts_ext,1,0) W,
    IF(buts_dom = buts_ext,1,0) D,
    IF(buts_dom < buts_ext,1,0) L,
    buts_dom F,
    buts_ext A,
    buts_dom-buts_ext GD,
    CASE WHEN buts_dom > buts_ext THEN 3 WHEN buts_dom = buts_ext THEN 1 ELSE 0 END PTS
  FROM pcs_matchs
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    id_candidate_ext,
    1,
    IF(buts_dom < buts_ext,1,0),
    IF(buts_dom = buts_ext,1,0),
    IF(buts_dom > buts_ext,1,0),
    buts_ext,
    buts_dom,
    buts_ext-buts_dom GD,
    CASE WHEN buts_dom < buts_ext THEN 3 WHEN buts_dom = buts_ext THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  FROM pcs_matchs WHERE validation=1 AND id_compet=1 AND id_season=1
) as tot
JOIN pcs_candidates t ON tot.Team=t.id_club
JOIN pcs_clubs c ON c.id=t.id_club
GROUP BY Team
ORDER BY SUM(Pts) DESC, SUM(GD) DESC;
```

Current result:

```
+------+---------------+---+---+---+---+---+----+-----+------------+
|      | Team          | P | W | D | L | F | A  | GD  | Pts        |
+------+---------------+---+---+---+---+---+----+-----+------------+
| 1    | Sevilla       | 3 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 6 | 2  | 4   | 9pts       |
+------+---------------+---+---+---+---+---+----+-----+------------+
| 2    | Real Zaragoza | 3 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 6 | 3  | 3   | 6pts       |
+------+---------------+---+---+---+---+---+----+-----+------------+
| 3    | Real Madrid   | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 6 | 6  | 0   | 4pts       |
+------+---------------+---+---+---+---+---+----+-----+------------+
| 4    | Barcelona     | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 5 | 5  | 0   | 4pts       |
+------+---------------+---+---+---+---+---+----+-----+------------+
| 5    | Deportivo     | 3 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 6  | -3  | 1pts       |
+------+---------------+---+---+---+---+---+----+-----+------------+
| 6    | Espanyol      | 3 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 4 | 8  | -4  | 1pts       |
+------+---------------+---+---+---+---+---+----+-----+------------+
```

I would like to add an extra column (current form) to the league table, based on the last 5 matches of each team before the current date. I need just simply, with adding one character per matches, if the team won then W, if tie then D, if lost then L. (if a team is not played 5 matches yet, then not add character to the column) somehow like this:

Desired result:

```
+---+---------------+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+------+-------------------------------------+
|   |               |   |   |   |   |   |   |    |      | Form (from newest result to oldest based on date of match) |
+---+---------------+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+------+-------------------------------------+
| 1 | Sevilla       | 3 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 6 | 2 | 4  | 9pts | WWW                                 |
+---+---------------+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+------+-------------------------------------+
| 2 | Real Zaragoza | 3 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 6 | 3 | 3  | 6pts | LWW                                 |
+---+---------------+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+------+-------------------------------------+
| 3 | Real Madrid   | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 6 | 6 | 0  | 4pts | WLD                                 |
+---+---------------+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+------+-------------------------------------+
| 4 | Barcelona     | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 5 | 5 | 0  | 4pts | WDL                                 |
+---+---------------+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+------+-------------------------------------+
| 5 | Deportivo     | 3 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 6 | -3 | 1pts | LDL                                 |
+---+---------------+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+------+-------------------------------------+
| 6 | Espanyol      | 3 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 4 | 8 | -4 | 1pts | LLD                                 |
+---+---------------+---+---+---+---+---+---+----+------+-------------------------------------+
```

https://www.flashscore.com/standings/pvZBCt9T/vHE9SNDE/#live

Thanks in advance!

UPDATED QUERY (it looks like it's working)

```
    SELECT
      shortname AS Team, Sum(P) AS P,Sum(W) AS W,Sum(D) AS D,Sum(L) AS L,
      SUM(F) as F,SUM(A) AS A,SUM(GD) AS GD,SUM(Pts) AS Pts, date_day AS dateday, group_concat(match_result ORDER BY date_day DESC)
    FROM(
      SELECT
        id_candidate_dom Team,
        1 P,
        IF(buts_dom > buts_ext,1,0) W,
        IF(buts_dom = buts_ext,1,0) D,
        IF(buts_dom < buts_ext,1,0) L,
        buts_dom F,
        buts_ext A,
        buts_dom-buts_ext GD,
        CASE WHEN buts_dom > buts_ext THEN 3 WHEN buts_dom = buts_ext THEN 1 ELSE 0 END PTS,
        CASE
      WHEN buts_dom > buts_ext THEN 'W'
      WHEN buts_dom = buts_ext THEN 'D'
      WHEN buts_dom < buts_ext THEN 'L'
    END match_result,
        date_day
      FROM pcs_matchs
      UNION ALL
      SELECT
        id_candidate_ext,
        1,
        IF(buts_dom < buts_ext,1,0),
        IF(buts_dom = buts_ext,1,0),
        IF(buts_dom > buts_ext,1,0),
        buts_ext,
        buts_dom,
        buts_ext-buts_dom GD,
        CASE WHEN buts_dom < buts_ext THEN 3 WHEN buts_dom = buts_ext THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
        CASE
      WHEN buts_dom < buts_ext THEN 'W'
      WHEN buts_dom = buts_ext THEN 'D'
      WHEN buts_dom > buts_ext THEN 'L'
    END match_result,
date_day
      FROM pcs_matchs WHERE validation=1 AND id_compet=1 AND id_season=1
    ) as tot
    JOIN pcs_candidates t ON tot.Team=t.id_club
    JOIN pcs_clubs c ON c.id=t.id_club
    GROUP BY Team
    ORDER BY SUM(Pts) DESC, SUM(GD) DESC
```

Comment: you can use ````CONCAT````  in an update (e.g. ````SET col = CONCAT(col,'new_value'))```` but it would probably be more useful, and better normalisation to have a different table for the results and do a join/sub query when you need to also display the form - what if (in the future) you want to show the form for the last 5 months, or years  instead depending on the page/query

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I don't want to add a different table for the results. (it would be huge work to change the whole site). Just simply I would like to add the abbrevation of result (W or D or L) per rounds to the league table last column (team form). I think some mysql expert could easily update my code for the desired result (like if a team wins then put a W char, and if the team lost in the next round then put L char, and if match result is a draw then D character). I don't want to show form of last few months. I hope someone help for me to update my code...

Comment: I don't think you can do this with the structure you have, because how can you know which were the last 3 results without linking the result to the date of the match - you can only get totals.  If you don't want to store the results then you can add 'form' as a column on your table and every time you update you can use a CONCAT as I suggested when you update the table - you would want to SUBSTR the last two characters ````SET form = CONCAT(SUBSTR(form, 2),'new_value'))```` - I can't see how you can do this otherwise without a relation between results and a date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have added `date_match` and the `match_result` columns to the querys in the UNION add the following column in the first SELECT clause:

```
group_concat(match_result ORDER BY date_match DESC)
```

For match result:

```
CASE
  WHEN buts_dom > buts_ext THEN 'W'
  WHEN buts_dom = buts_ext THEN 'D'
  WHEN buts_dom < buts_ext THEN 'L'
END match_result
```

Comment: there is no match_result column is there?

Comment: yes, in the pcs_matchs table there is only buts_dom (home goal) and buts_ext (away goal) columns, but there is a date_match column

Comment: Hello Sal, Thanks for your answer, I have added the updated code to the bottom of my question: The result: #1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns. And the name of match date column is date_day, earlier I wrote wrong this.

Comment: @Terminus: You are missing date_day in the 2nd query of the UNION.

Comment: Many thanks Sal, it looks like it's working, I am testing now with more results. I hope it will works, thanks again!